# How to create a dexterity content type not indexed at all?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I would like to create a dexterity content type which is not registred at all in the portal_catalog.

I don't want to unindex it after creation but really I want it to never be indexed in the portal_catalog. Is this possible  and how ?

This is for performance reason and because my content type doesn't provide any of the index (except the path index)

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom class for your content type. Override the _getCatalogTool method (inherited from Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware.CMFCatalogAware) and make it return None.